# Accessing the variable from another model in my controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, controller, haml

So, I want to access one of the variables from my quotes model:

```
class Quotes < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :quotes1, :quotes10, :quotes2, :quotes3, :quotes4, :quotes5, :quotes6, :quotes7, :quotes8, :quotes9

  attr_accessor :quotes1, :quotes10, :quotes2, :quotes3, :quotes4, :quotes5, :quotes6,   :quotes7, :quotes8, :quotes9
end
```

Here is my pages controller, because I want to access it in `views/pages/home.html.haml`:

```
def home
  @quotes = Quotes.find(:first, :order => "RANDOM()")
end
```

And here is my `home.html.haml`:

```
%h2
  Client's opinions
%p
  =@quotes
```

All of these quotes from 1...10 are strings, and have default values, they are not nil. And still I am not getting anything on my home page. Why?

Comment: I think your Quote model is way off. Take a look at the [Rails docs about relations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html). I think you need a relation like: Client has_many Quotes.

Comment: Shouldn't I be able to access the model from any controller I like? For my home page I don't have a model, I just have a controller. And I need to have the qoutes in my home page. The "client's opinions" is just a heading.

Comment: Yes you can use any model in any controller.

Comment: So, what am I doing wrong then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

controller:

```
quotes_number = (srand % 10) + 1
@quotes = Quotes.find(:first, :order => "RANDOM()").send(:"quotes#{quote_number}")
```

view:

```
%h2
  Client's opinions
%p
  =@quotes
```

Comment: But I want it to give me one random qoute. And that code is not working, I get undefined method error.

Comment: Oh, you really had to use associations for this. So you will have a ```client``` model and ```quota``` model. ```client``` has_many ```quotas```.

Comment: It is not my application. I am jumping in half way.So, how can I get these qoutes to show randomly on my home page?

Comment: Now, I get this error: undefined method `quotes2' for nil:NilClass
Why is it so hard to do this?